# Compact command execution time is more with MongoDB-3.6

Tags: mongodb

We are using the compact command in order to reduce the storage space of data and index.

As we have upgraded MongoDB version from MongoDB-3.4.0 to MongoDB-3.6.17.

We observed that the command compact execution time is more with MongoDB-3.6 and it took very less time with MongoDB-3.4.

Any one of you faced this kind of issue kindly confirm.

Below are the environment details

1. OS: Windows 10
2. Architecture: “x64”,
3. Platform:  “Java/AdoptOpenJDK/11.0.6” ,
4. mongodb Journals are enabled by default
5. Mongod server version: db version v3.6.17

Thanks & Regards,
Ram

Answer (score 0):

You can try using 
mongod --repair or after connecting run db.repairDatabase() command.